# (NameError: global name is not defined) error over passing a list to a function

Tags: python

I am sorry to post a long code. I have extracted the parts of my code where the list `lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` is generated and used. There is an error of linking the functions where this list has been used. The`generate_t_u()` function is called inside `time()` function but `time()` function wouldn't recognize this list as its not been passed there. But if I pass it in this function then I have to make changes in the main as well. And again I will get the same error.

```
def time(transcriptionFile) :
    """ This function changes the time values in secs from the transcription file and keeps a list of start time for each phoneme. """
    with open("transcriptions.txt", "r") as tFile :
        timeList = []
        t_u = 0.0
        for line in tFile :
            li = line.split()
            if li :
                start_time = (int(li[0]) / 10000000.)
                timeList.append(start_time)
                #print timeList 

    generate_t_u(timeList, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist)

def generate_t_u(timeList, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist)
    """ It generates the regular time intervals t(u) values for sampling. """
    i = 0        
    while i < len(timeList) - 1 :
        # if the number is in the range
        # do the calculations and move to the next number
        if t_u > timeList[i] and t_u < timeList[i + 1] :
            #print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is between',
            #print "start:", timeList[i], " and end: ", timeList[i+1]
            poly = poly_coeff(timeList[i], timeList[i + 1], t_u)
            Newton(poly, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i],  lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i + 1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number is at the lower boundary of the range, no need of calculation as u = 0
        elif t_u == timeList[i] :
            #print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is on the boundary of',
            #print "start:", timeList[i], " and end: ", timeList[i+1]
            #print "u : 0"
            lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(0, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i], lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i + 1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number is at the upper boundary of the range, no need of calculation as u = 1
        elif t_u == timeList[i + 1] :
            #print "\n The t_u value:", t_u, 'is on the boundary of',
            #print "start:", timeList[i], " and end: ", timeList[i+1]
            #print " u : 1"
            lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(1, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i], lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i + 1])
            t_u = t_u + 0.04 # regular time interval

        # if the number isn't in the range, move to the next range
        else :
            i += 1

def Newton(poly, p0, p3) :
    """ Newton's method for finding the root of a polynomial. Here the root is the 'u' value"""
    poly_diff = poly_differentiate(poly)
    counter = 0
    epsilon = 0.000000000001
    x = 0.5 # initial guess value

    while True:
        x_n = x - (float(poly_substitute(poly, x)) / poly_substitute(poly_diff, x))
        counter += 1
        if abs(x_n - x) < epsilon :
            break
        x = x_n
        #print "\tIteration " , counter , " : ", x_n

     print "u:", (x_n)

    lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(x_n, p0, p3)      

def param_lists_separate(pList) :
    """ Separating the parameter values of each feature into individual lists """
    v = [[inner[1][i] for outer in pList for inner in outer]
        for i in range(len(pList[0][0][1]))]

    lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist = v[0]
    lips_part_plist = v[1]
    lips_spread_plist = v[2]
    jaw_open_plist = v[3]
    lips_round_plist = v[4]  

    return lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist

def lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(x_n, p0, p3) :
    """ Calculating sampling points using rational bezier curve equation"""
    u = x_n
    p1 = p0
    p2 = p3

    lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * p0 + 3 * u * math.pow(1 - u, 2) * p1 \
                                 + 3 * (1 - u) * math.pow(u, 2) * p2 + math.pow(u, 3) * p3
    lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u = lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u * w
    d = math.pow(1 - u, 3) * w + 3 * u * w * math.pow(1 - u, 2) + 3 * (1 - u) * w * math.pow(u, 2) + math.pow(u, 3) * w
    lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u = lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u / d

    print "\n p(u) values for the feature lower lip under upper list \n"
    print "p(u): ", lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u
    return lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    time("transcriptions.txt")
```

The error is:

> NameError: global name 'lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist' is not defined.

This error is on the line `lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(0, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i], lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[i + 1])` from the `time()` function.

Comment: Where is the value for `lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` supposed to come from?

Comment: It complains that it's undefined because it is. Do you understand what you're doing, or are you trying to work with someone else's code?

Comment: @interjay The value for lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist comes from the pList passed in param_lists_separate() function.

Comment: @Chris It's my code. Like I mentioned in the question, I have just just extracted the parts of the code.

Comment: @eryksun If I call pList in time() function then I have to add the argument in main as well where the time() function is called and if I do that I get the same error.

Comment: @ eryksun Instead of returning lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist from param_lists_separate() function I should return v? And param_lists_separate() function is called in another function which is not posted here. Or I think I kind of know what is going on here. I would look at the code again and edit the question if I have to. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Consider this line in the `time` function:

```
def time(transcriptionFile) :
    ...
    generate_t_u(timeList, lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist)
```

`lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` is not defined in the time function, so Python looks for it in the global scope. It is not defined there either, so Python raises a `NameError`, saying the variable `lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` is not defined.

---

By the way, the traceback error message includes a line number indicating what line caused the `NameError`. It will help you (and us) zero in on the problem to include the line number.

Comment: I have edited the question and added a line where the error is generated. I should pass the list "lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist" in the time function as an argument right? And then I have to make the change in main() as well. But I get the same error even when I do that.

Answer (score 2):

Should `lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` be a return value of `generate_t_u`?  Try changing `generate_t_u` to:

```
def generate_t_u(time_list):
    lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist = []
    # ... the function remains the same
    return lower_lip_upper_list_plist
```

I'm not sure where `param_lists_separate` is called but it looks like the bindings in it are expected to be global as well.  A similar problem exists in `generate_t_u` since `t_u` is not bound there -- if this refers to the `t_u` in `time`, then it should probably be passed in as a parameter.  If you have a number of related bindings and methods that act upon the data, then you should probably consider creating a class that ties the data and the operations together.

Consider doing something like the following instead:

```
class NewtonsMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        # change global names into properties of ``self``
        self.lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist = []
        self.lips_part_plist = []
        self.lips_spread_plist = []
        self.jaw_open_plist = []
        self.lips_round_plist = []
        self.t_u = 0.0
        self.time_list = []
        # initialize from the data file
        with open(file_name) as file_ref:
            for line in file_ref:
                data = line.split()
                if data:
                    start_time = (int(data[0]) / 10000000.0)
                    self.time_list.append(start_time)
    def _lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(self, x_n, point):
       (u, p1, p2) = (x_n, self.lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[point],
                      self.lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist[point + 1])
       # if lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u is used elsewhere, then it
       # might make sense to change it to a property
       lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u = ...
       return lower_lip_under_upper_list_p_u
    def _generate_t_u(self):
       (i, t_u) = (0, 0.0)
       while i < len(self.time_list) - 1:
           if t_u > self.time_list[i] and t_u < time_list[i + 1]:
               poly = poly_coeff(self.time_list[i], self.time_list[i + 1], t_u)
               self._apply_newton(poly, i)
           elif t_u == self.time_list[i]:
               self._lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(0, i)
               t_u += 0.04
           elif t_u == self.time_list[i + 1]:
               self._lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(1, i)
               t_u += 0.04
           else:
               i += 1
    def _apply_newton(self, poly, point):
        poly_diff = poly_differentiate(poly)
        (epsilon, x) = (0.0000000001, 0.5)
        while True:
            x_n = x - (...)
            if abs(x_n - x) < epsilon:
                break
            x = x_n
        self._lower_lip_under_upper_list_bezier(x_n, point)
```

One of the most basic precepts of object-oriented programming is bundling algorithms with the data that they process and/or require.  You can apply this idea here.  Your global bindings will become properties of the object so they are always available as properties of `self` within instance methods.  As you may have noticed, passing the values from `lower_lip_under_upper_list_plist` and the like is no longer necessary.  All that you need to do is pass the index into the list since the list itself is a property of the object.

Refactoring your algorithm into a `class` should remove the need for globals everywhere.  It will also minimize the number of parameters and let you concentrate on implementing the algorithm in a clean and modular way.

Comment: @ D.Shawley Thank you. I really appreciate your help. But I am doing python and complex programming for the first time. It is the algorithm for my research. Since I am not really a good programmer, using classes would confuse me further. Therefore I am just using functions and its easy for me to see the flow of the algorithm though its not a good programming practice. Can I explain my code to you in detail so that you can point me towards the right direction?